# Is Linq to XML better suited for small files?

Tags: linq-to-xml

In windows phone 7.5 data recepie cookbook author claims that Linq to XML is better suited for smaller files, whereas the legacy XmlReader, XmlWriter classes are best for for large files. Is it true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The reason for this is, that LINQ to XML parses the whole document when you create the XDocument, while XmlReader is 'forward only', because it uses a stream.

Mike Taulty has a great blog-post on the topic. See [here](http://mtaulty.com/CommunityServer/blogs/mike_taultys_blog/archive/2007/09/08/9803.aspx).